# the value of alice should be 2 but it returns 1

Tags: python-3.x

```
a = [17, 28, 30]
b = [99, 16, 8]
alice = 0
bob = 0
a0, a1, a2 = a[0], a[1], a[2]
b0, b1, b2 = b[0], b[1], b[2]


if a0 > b0 or a1 > b1 or a2 > b2:
   alice += 1

if b0 > a0 or b1 > a1 or b2 > a2:
   bob += 1

if a0 == b0 or a1 == b1 or a2 == b2:
   alice += 0
   bob += 0

print(alice, bob)
```

the value of alice should be 2 but it returns 1.
i want it to function like this, If a[x]>b[x], then Alice is 1 awarded  point, If b[x]>a[x], then Bob is 1 awarded  point, If a[x]=b[x], then neither person receives a point.

Comment: What is `alice += 0` doing?

Comment: You only did the "if a0> b0 or a1> b1", etc statement once. So it looks to see if any of those conditions is true, and then increments alice by one, just once!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
a = [17, 28, 30]
b = [99, 16, 8]

alice = len([i for i, j in zip(a, b) if i > j])
bob = len([j for i, j in zip(a, b) if i < j])
equal = len([j for i, j in zip(a, b) if i == j])
print('alice = ',alice)
print('bob = ',bob)
print('equal = ',equal)
```